# jQuery: Toggling between 3 classes (initially)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen several posts here on SO but they are too specific in functionality and structure, and what I'm looking for is something more universal that I or anyone can use anywhere.

All I need is to have a button that when clicked can cycle between **3** classes. But if the case arises to have to cycle through 4, 5 or more classes, that the script can be easily scaled.

As of this moment I am able to 'cycle' between two classes which is basically more "toggling" than cycling, so for that I have:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle classes</a>
<div class="class1">...</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
  $('div').toggleClass('class1 class2');
});
```

Here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xRYJL/) of this.

Now, you would (well, I) think that adding a third class to the method would work, but it doesn't:

```
$('div').toggleClass('class1 class2 class3');
```

What happens is that the toggling starts happening between `class1` and `class3` only.

So this is where I have my initial problem: *How to have the Toggle button cycle sequentially through **3** classes?*

And then: What if someone needs to cycle to 4, 5 or more classes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
  var classes = ['class1','class2','class3'];
  $('div').each(function(){
    this.className = classes[($.inArray(this.className, classes)+1)%classes.length];
  });
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/FSFpZ/)

Comment: This is **exactly** what I wanted to accomplish, and it's so easy to scale as well. Huge plus adding the demo. Thanks a million *dystroy*.

Comment: Definitely prefer your way, much more succinct.

Comment: Works perfectly with classes! I have something similar case, where I should toggle between data attribute values (data-align=left|center|right). Do you have a nice solution for that too ;) ?

Comment: But wouldn't this solution overwrite any other class that should not be touched by this logic?

Comment: @Chuck You're right this isn't compatible with using other classes on those elements. Right now, more than 4 years later and with new tools, I'd use classList to easily add and remove classes.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another approach:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('one')) {
    $(this).removeClass('one').addClass('two');
} else if ($(this).hasClass('two')) {
    $(this).removeClass('two').addClass('three');
} else if ($(this).hasClass('three')) {
    $(this).removeClass('three').addClass('one');
}
```

Comment: While this does not scale as well as the main answer, I appreciate the simplicity and understandability of it for someone new to jquery.

Comment: wouldnt this be more elegant with || operator , or is that not possible?

Answer (score 4):

```
var classes = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'],
    currentClass = 0;

$('.toggle').click(function () {

    $('div').removeClass(classes[currentClass]);

    if (currentClass + 1 < classes.length)
    {
        currentClass += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        currentClass = 0;
    }

    $('div').addClass(classes[currentClass]);

});
```

Something like that should work OK :)

Tinker IO link - https://tinker.io/1048b

Comment: Toddish, I tried your code but it didn't work. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: I think the error is setting class to `currentClass` instead of `classes[currentClass]`

Comment: Ah! Nice, it works great. Gave you an upvote man, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and I can stack as many as I want, then wrap around easily.

```
switch($('div.sel_object table').attr('class'))
    {
    case "A":   $('div.sel_object table').toggleClass('A B'); break;
    case "B":   $('div.sel_object table').toggleClass('B C'); break;
    case "C":   $('div.sel_object table').toggleClass('C D'); break;
    case "D":   $('div.sel_object table').toggleClass('D A'); break;                
    }
```

Comment: Light encouragement to share a more versatile function with undefined number of items and a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Cycles through the index of classes and toggles from one to ther other.

```
var classes = ['border-top','border-right','border-bottom','border-left'];
var border = 'border-top';
var index = 0;
var timer = setInterval( function() {
    var callback = function(response) {
        index = ( ++index == 4 ? 0 : index );
        $(element).html("text").toggleClass( border + " " + classes[index] );
        border = classes[index];
        };
    }, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted [user3353523's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22028134/1762224) into a jQuery plugin.

```js
(function() {
  $.fn.rotateClass = function(cls1, cls2, cls3) {
    if ($(this).hasClass(cls1)) {
      return $(this).removeClass(cls1).addClass(cls2);
    } else if ($(this).hasClass(cls2)) {
      return $(this).removeClass(cls2).addClass(cls3);
    } else if ($(this).hasClass(cls3)) {
      return $(this).removeClass(cls3).addClass(cls1);
    } else {
      return $(this).toggleClass(cls1); // Default case.
    }
  }
})(jQuery);

$('#click-me').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).rotateClass('cls-1', 'cls-2', 'cls-3');
});
```

```css
#click-me {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  border: thin solid #777;
  margin: calc(49vh - 2.4em) auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.cls-1 { background: #FFAAAA; }
.cls-2 { background: #AAFFAA; }
.cls-3 { background: #AAAAFF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click-me" class="unselectable">Click Me!</div>
```

---

### Dynamic Approach

```js
(function() {
  $.fn.rotateClass = function() {
    let $this = this,
        clsList = arguments.length > 1 ? [].slice.call(arguments) : arguments[0];
    if (clsList.length === 0) {
      return $this;
    }
    if (typeof clsList === 'string') {
      clsList = clsList.indexOf(' ') > -1 ? clsList.split(/\s+/) : [ clsList ];
    }
    if (clsList.length > 1) {
      for (let idx = 0; idx < clsList.length; idx++) {
        if ($this.hasClass(clsList[idx])) {
          let nextIdx = (idx + 1) % clsList.length,
              nextCls = clsList.splice(nextIdx, 1);
          return $this.removeClass(clsList.join(' ')).addClass(nextCls[0]);
        }
      }
    }
    return $this.toggleClass(clsList[0]);
  }
})(jQuery);

$('#click-me').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).rotateClass('cls-1', 'cls-2', 'cls-3');     // Parameters
  //$(this).rotateClass(['cls-1', 'cls-2', 'cls-3']); // Array
  //$(this).rotateClass('cls-1 cls-2 cls-3');         // String
});
```

```css
#click-me {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  border: thin solid #777;
  margin: calc(49vh - 2.4em) auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.cls-1 { background: #FFAAAA; }
.cls-2 { background: #AAFFAA; }
.cls-3 { background: #AAAAFF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click-me" class="unselectable">Click Me!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Polywhirl. What if you have more than 3 classes then? The selected answer is quite scalable in this regard. Also, clicking on a `div` rather than a link for example feels weird :p. Thanks for the plugin.

Comment: @RicardoZea Well, I simply converted the logic into a plugin. I have created a dynamic one below. ;)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="example" class="red">color sample</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green'];
    var tmp;
    setInterval(function(){
        tmp && $('#example').removeClass(tmp);
        tmp = colors.pop();
        $('#example').addClass(tmp);
        colors.unshift(tmp);
    }, 1000);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c3k6x9zh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Another version that uses [`classList replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Not supported by all browsers yet.

```js
var classes = ["class1", "class2", "class3"];
var index = 0;
var classList = document.querySelector("div").classList;
const len = classes.length;

$('.toggle').click(function() {
  classList.replace(classes[index++ % len], classes[index % len]);
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  background: yellow;
}

.class2 {
  background: orange;
}

.class3 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle classes</a>
<div class="class1">
  look at me!
</div>
```