# How to change between 3 images with javascript onClick event?

Tags: javascript

I have simple html and Javascript code shown below where image1 is displayed, and when it is clicked it changes to image2. I am having a problem extending this to a third image such that if image2 is clicked, it changes to image3 and finally if image3 is clicked that it returns to image1 and the cycle can be repeated once more. Can anyone suggest to me what the best approach is because I think that the way I am currently doing it for 2 images won't work for what I have described. Thanks

Note:This is a problem I have encountered for exam preparation and as such I can't use JQuery-must be JavaScript.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
function preloadImages() { 
Image1=new Image(); 
Image1.src = "image1.jpg";
} 

</script> 
</head> 
<body onLoad="preloadImages();"> 
<img name="myButton" src="image2.jpg"
onClick="document.myButton.src='image1.jpg';" 
onClick="document.myButton.src='image2.jpg';"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about event listeners and an array of images that can be extended to any number you like

```
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
        <img id="myButton" src="image2.jpg" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'],
                i = 1;

            // preload
            for (var j=images.length; j--;) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = images[j];
            }

            // event handler
            document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                this.src = images[i >= images.length - 1 ? i = 0 : ++i];
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/567yy/)

Comment: Could you explain this line of code a little for me if you don't mind. I'm having trouble understanding what is going on here. Thanks-sorry I'm very new to JavaScript (no problem if you don't explain-appreciate your answer!) Thanks. 'this.src = images[i >= images.length - 1 ? i = 0 : ++i];'

Comment: It's a ternary, a shortened if/else statement. If `i` is over the number of images, we start at `0` again (the first image), otherwise we use `i + 1` to get the next image etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can toggle between three classes and attach different images to all classes to see how to toggle between three classes check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200833/jquery-toggling-between-3-classes-initially).
You can also use an array and assign src of images to the array and assign one to your img at a time.Hope it helps

```
var mylinks = new Array();
mylinks[0] = "abc.jpg";
mylinks[1] = "xyz.jpg";
mylinks[2] = "lmn.jpg";
```

first assign one say `(var i=0)` and you assign `mylinks[i]` and then `(i=i+1)` and assign `mylinks[i]` and keep on doing it till `i> mylinks.length` then start-over i.e `i=0;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer-I was trying a few things with arrays already so might give that another go. I should have mentioned in my post that this is for preparation for an exam and I can't use jQuery-just JavaScript. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 

var imagesNames = ["Image1.jpg", "Image2.jpg", "Image3.jpg"];

function preloadImages() { 
  for (var i = 0 ; i < imagesNames.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageNames[i];
  }
} 

var imageIndex = 0;
img.onclick = function() {
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex > imagesNames.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }

  document.getElementById("myButton").src = imageNames[imageIndex];
}

</script> 
</head> 
<body onLoad="preloadImages();"> 
<img id="myButton">
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Slight improvement, since `imageNames[imageNames.length]` never exists try changing `imageIndex > imageNames.length` to `imageIndex >= imageNames.length` or `imageIndex > imageNames.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<img name="myButton" id="myButton" data-img="1" src="image1.jpg" />
```

**JS:**

```
var imgList = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg", "image3.jpg" ];

var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
myButton.onclick = function( e ){
    var elem = e.target,
    imageIndex = parseInt(elem.dataset.img,10);
    if( imageIndex <= (imgList.length -1) ) {
        elem.src = imgList[imageIndex++];
        elem.dataset.img = imageIndex;
    } else {
        elem.src = imgList[0];
        elem.dataset.img = 1;
    }
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/ry6hS/