# toggleClass between three different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle between three classes every 4 seconds, but I can't figure out how to get the third class working. This is what I have so far (which works)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.myClass.class1').toggleClass('class2')
  }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Adding another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200833/jquery-toggling-between-3-classes-initially/49143393#49143393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [`classList replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) the following would work.

```js
var classes = ["class1", "class2", "class3"];
var index = 0;
var classList = document.querySelector(".myClass").classList;

setInterval(function() {
  classList.replace(classes[index++ % 3], classes[index % 3]);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.class1 {
  background: yellow;
}

.class2 {
  background: orange;
}

.class3 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass class1">
  look at me!
</div>
```

If you can't use `replace` (not supported by all browsers) you could replace that line with this jquery version:

```js
var classes = ["class1", "class2", "class3"];
var index = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  $(".myClass").removeClass(classes[index++ % 3]).addClass(classes[index % 3]);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.class1 {
  background: yellow;
}

.class2 {
  background: orange;
}

.class3 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass class1">
  look at me!
</div>
```

Comment: The first suggestion gives me an Uncaught DOMException, and the second one only seems to toggle between class1 and class 3!

Comment: Not all browsers support `replace` unfortunately. I converted the second one into a snippet and it works fine. Maybe you're missing something?

Comment: Oh man, I wasn't separating the class names with " "! I had ["class1, class2, class3"] This works now! Thank you!

Comment: Ah. Good catch. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

this method allows you to add more classes if you want an example

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval(function(){
$('.myClass.class1').toggleClass('class2 class3')
 }, 4000);
 });
```

Comment: This seems to only toggle between class1 and class3

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you store all the classes in an array and increment an index to rotate through the array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const allClasses = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];
  let index = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.myClass').removeClass(allClasses[index % 3]);
    index = index + 1;
    $('.myClass').addClass(allClasses[index % 3]);
  }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: this gives me Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

on the index = index + 1 line

Comment: Fixed, changed `const` into `let`. I can't really test myself since I don't have the full code, this is just to give you the general direction

Comment: No errors, but it now toggles between myClass.class1 and myClass.class1 class 1, class2, class 3